# foreach collapse Bootstrap and JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

the one who searched the whole page and I have tried several codes related to this topic, when I press the collapse the other collapse open, how can I make it open only the collapse that I am pressing, I leave my code

```
            $.each(result, function (i, item) {
            var j = 0;
            console.log(result);

            $(".card-group").append("<div class='col-md-2 mt-5 me-4'>" + "<div class='card text-center text-white bg-dark mb-3'> " +


                "<div class='card-body'>" +
                "<h5 class='card-title'>" +
                "<a class='text-white' >" + item.variable1 + "</a>" +
                
                
                 "</h5>" +
                "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-floating' style='background-color: #FF6633' data-mdb-toggle='collapse' data-mdb-target='#collapseExample' aria-expanded='false' aria-controls='collapseExample'>"
                + "<i class='bi bi-caret-down-fill'>" + "</i>" +
                "</button>" +

                "<div class='collapse mt-3' id='collapseExample'> " + item.variable2[0] + "<br>" + item.variable2[1] + "<br>" + item.variable2[2] + "</div>" +
                "</div>" +
                "<a  class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' style='background-color: #FF6633; font-size: medium; color: #202020; font-weight:bold;'> " + item.Year + " </a>" +
               
                "</div>" +
                
                "</div>" 
                );

        });
```

Comment: I dont see any code handling the click event.

Comment: What I want is to concatenate the collapse, the variable i of the foreach, but I don't know how, this so that the corresponding one opens and not all the collapse opens